# Outside Click to reset color?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make background of color to be changed to default color of background same as it was before changing it with **Red** or **Yellow** from input form when I click outside of the input box

### I tried to use 'null' or 'none' but didn't worked?

```js
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

function changeBackground(x){
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;
}
function outsideClick(e) {
  if(e.target == backgroundColor) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
</head>
  <body>          
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Change Color</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: What is `if(e.target == backgroundColor)` trying to achieve? `backgroundColor` is not a variable you have defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change from:

```
if(e.target == backgroundColor) {
```

to:

```
if(e.target.tagName != 'SELECT') {
```

```js
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

function changeBackground(x){
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;
}
function outsideClick(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName != 'SELECT') {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">Change Color</label>
    <select id="inputState" class="form-control" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked thanks but can you explain why you added tagName != 'SELECT', what's the meaning of that because i am a bit new to JS

Comment: You may change that with e.tartget.id != 'inputState'.  In this way the test is more accurate

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
body.style.backgroundColor = '';
```

it will fallback to the color it has set in the class.

Comment: "function outsideClick(e) {
 
 if(e.target == backgroundColor) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}"
Changed code and still outside Click doesn't changes it stays red still

Answer (score 2):

To reset any CSS property, you can use the `initial` or the `unset` value (they do slightly different things).

So here's how it's done:

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#inputState")

window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

select.addEventListener('change', () => changeBackground(select.value));


function changeBackground(x){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;
}

function outsideClick(e) { 
  if(e.target === select) {
    changeBackground(select.value);
  } else {
    changeBackground("initial");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Change Color</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but can you tell why you added !== document.querySelector("#inputState") , because i am new to JS

Comment: @Behar `something !== something2` is an expression which gives `true` if `something` isn't the same as `something2`. So in my answer above `e.target !== document.querySelector("#inputState")` means that only reset color if the element that you clicked isn't your select element. (`document.querySelector("#something")` is the same as `document.getElementById("something")`, and it gives the element with ID of `something`).

Comment: oh got it thank you man for your help and explanation, upvoted aswell ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

function changeBackground(x){
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;
}

function outsideClick(e) {  
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  body.style.backgroundColor = '';
}
```

```html
</head>
  <body onclick="outsideClick(event)">          
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="inputState">Change Color</label>
<select id="inputState" class="form-control" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
  <option selected>choose...</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks mate, but it seems a problem with code because color red and yellow doesn't show up

Comment: @Behar in above snippet red and yellow show up (in my computer on chrome browser) - in your browser they don't show up?

Comment: yeah it doesn't and i use chrome too. maybe it's from my browser that has blocked something